# How to left-justify some Bootstrap nav content and right-justify other content?

Tags: navbar, bootstrap-5

I have a Bootstrap 5.x navbar with the following code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-custom navbar-dark fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid px-5">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="../main.aspx">
                <img src="../images/mainlogo_150x136.jpg" class="d-inline-block align-text-middle">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mb-2 mb-sm-0">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/main.aspx">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/directory.aspx">Directory</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/notices.aspx">Notices</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/events.aspx">Upcoming Events</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/members/messages.aspx">Message Center</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/aboutus.aspx">About Us</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav mb-2 mb-sm-0">
                    <% if ( HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ) {  %>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/members/signout.aspx">Logout</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/members/myaccount.aspx">Account</a></li> 
                    <% }   
                       else {%>  
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/signin.aspx">Login</a></li>
                        <li ckass="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/register.aspx">Register</a></li> 
                    <%} %>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to left-justify the main page links and, at the same time, right-justify the signin/signout and register/account links.  I have tried a number of  solutions I found on SO but nothing seems to work right.
Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it (finally!)
Here's code that works:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-custom navbar-dark fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="mx-auto">
                <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/main.aspx">
                    <img src="~/images/mainlogo_150x136.jpg" runat="server" class="d-inline-block align-text-middle" />
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/main.aspx">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/directory.aspx">Directory</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/notices.aspx">Notices</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/events.aspx">Upcoming Events</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/members/messages.aspx">Message Center</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/aboutus.aspx">About Us</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav d-flex mr-auto">
                    <% if ( HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ) {  %>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/members/signout.aspx">Logout</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/members/myaccount.aspx">My Account</a></li> 
                    <% }
                    else {%>  
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/signin.aspx">Login</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/register.aspx">Register</a></li> 
                    <%} %>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

It required setting `class="navbar-nav me-auto"` on the first `<ul>` tag, and `class="navbar-nav d-flex mr-auto"` on te second `<ul>` tag.

Now it works as expected!